# Sort by numbers in a specific column

Tags: perl, unix, sorting

I have data in this format (tab separated columns)...

```
Name_00001  Annotation_1    gene    329412  330509  .   -   .   ID=TAXON_00029;Name=TAXON_00029
Name_00001  Annotation_1    mRNA    329412  330509  .   -   .   ID=TAXON_00029T0;Parent=TAXON_00029
Name_00001  Annotation_1    exon    193957  194252  .   +   .   ID=exon:TAXON_00022T0:1;Parent=TAXON_00022T0
Name_00001  Annotation_1    exon    195500  197118  .   +   .   ID=exon:TAXON_00022T0:2;Parent=TAXON_00022T0
```

...and I would like to sort by the first 5 numbers in column 9 in ascending order. I.e. so the file looks like this:

```
Name_00001  Annotation_1    exon    193957  194252  .   +   .   ID=exon:TAXON_00022T0:1;Parent=TAXON_00022T0
Name_00001  Annotation_1    exon    195500  197118  .   +   .   ID=exon:TAXON_00022T0:2;Parent=TAXON_00022T0    
Name_00001  Annotation_1    gene    329412  330509  .   -   .   ID=TAXON_00029;Name=TAXON_00029
Name_00001  Annotation_1    mRNA    329412  330509  .   -   .   ID=TAXON_00029T0;Parent=TAXON_00029
```

I have tried to use Unix or Perl, but my skills are very limited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to sort by the first 5 *digits* in column 9,
that is something you cannot literally explain to `sort`, but as you suggested, `perl` is more flexible:

```
perl -e 'sub key { 0+((split(/\s+/,$_[0]))[8] =~ /(\d{5})/)[0] }; print sort { key($a) <=> key($b) } <>' < unsorted > sorted
```

This assumes the five digits always exist and are always consecutive but you can take it from there.
It's better to put the code into a file, add `use warnings; use strict;` and increase legibility:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub key {
    my $line = $_[0];
    my @fields = split(/\s+/,$line);
    my ($keystring) = $fields[8] =~ /(\d{5})/;
    my $key = 0 + $keystring;
    $key
}

print sort { key($a) <=> key($b) } <>
```

Comment: Have I misunderstood something here? I get this error message: syntax error at -e line 1, near "/(\d{5})/ }"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors. I used this command: `perl -e 'sub key { ((split(/\s+/,$_[0]))[8] =~ /(\d{5})/ }; print sort { key($a) <=> key($b) } <>' < sort-test.txt > sort-test-out.txt`

Comment: Sorry, I pasted in the wrong version :(  This one should be better.

Comment: I have also added an expanded version.

Answer (score 3):

no need of perl.use sort command in unix.

```
sort -k 9 -n your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
Name_00001      Annotation_1    gene    329412  330509  .       -       .       ID=TAXON_00029;Name=TAXON_00029
Name_00001      Annotation_1    mRNA    329412  330509  .       -       .       ID=TAXON_00029T0;Parent=TAXON_00029
Name_00001      Annotation_1    exon    193957  194252  .       +       .       ID=exon:TAXON_00022T0:1;Parent=TAXON_00022T0
Name_00001      Annotation_1    exon    195500  197118  .       +       .       ID=exon:TAXON_00022T0:2;Parent=TAXON_00022T0
> sort -k 9 -n temp
Name_00001      Annotation_1    exon    193957  194252  .       +       .       ID=exon:TAXON_00022T0:1;Parent=TAXON_00022T0
Name_00001      Annotation_1    exon    195500  197118  .       +       .       ID=exon:TAXON_00022T0:2;Parent=TAXON_00022T0
Name_00001      Annotation_1    gene    329412  330509  .       -       .       ID=TAXON_00029;Name=TAXON_00029
Name_00001      Annotation_1    mRNA    329412  330509  .       -       .       ID=TAXON_00029T0;Parent=TAXON_00029
```

tested for the comment too:

```
> cat temp
Name_00001      Annotation_1    mRNA    329412  330509  .       -       .       ID=TAXON_00013T0;Parent=TAXON_00029
Name_00001      Annotation_1    exon    193957  194252  .       +       .       ID=exon:TAXON_00002T0:1;Parent=TAXON_00022T0
> sort -k 9 -n temp
Name_00001      Annotation_1    exon    193957  194252  .       +       .       ID=exon:TAXON_00002T0:1;Parent=TAXON_00022T0
Name_00001      Annotation_1    mRNA    329412  330509  .       -       .       ID=TAXON_00013T0;Parent=TAXON_00029
```

Comment: Is this correct? I tried on a different file. This command puts this "ID=TAXON_00013T0" in column 9 before this "ID=TAXON_00002T0". The second number is smaller than the first

Comment: are you sure?.i tried with the same numbers and its printing correctly